# Reading and Writing numpy Float Complex 128

Tags: python, numpy

I have a block of code given to me that generates a file containing numpy Float Complex 128 array from streamed data from a SDR. Another part of this same program can read in the file containing numpy Float Complex 128 using `np.load`

When I try to generate my own Float Complex 128 array by writing the same SDR data to a Float Complex 128 and then read it in I get the error:

```
File "c:\Users\Owner\test_pyrtlsdr\.venv\Lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 462, in load raise ValueError("Cannot load file containing pickled data "
ValueError: Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False
```

The code I have bene given that is able to generate a file looks like:

```
async def run_readonly(sample_config: SampleConfig, filename: str, max_samples: int):
chunk_size = sample_config.read_size
nrows = max_samples // sample_config.read_size
if nrows * chunk_size < max_samples:
    nrows += 1
samples = np.zeros((nrows, chunk_size), dtype=np.complex128)
sample_config = SampleConfig(read_size=chunk_size)
reader = SampleReader(sample_config)

async with reader:
    await reader.open_stream()
    i = 0
    count = 0
    async for _samples in reader:
        if count == 0:
            print(f'{_samples.size=}')
        samples[i,:] = _samples
        count += _samples.size
        # print(f'{i}\t{reader.aio_queue.qsize()=}\t{count=}')
        i += 1
        if count >= max_samples:
            break
samples = samples.flatten()[:max_samples]
np.save(filename, samples)
```

I have confirmed that the file generated from above is of dtype=floatcomplex128

In another class I have that receives 250000 samples from the SDR every 0.1 of a second, and should keep appending samples as they come into file:

```
class Processor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.f = open('testing_gain.fc32', 'wb') 

    def process(self, samples: SamplesT):
    #for testing - log to file
    self.f.write(samples.astype(np.complex128).tobytes())
```

The problem with the above is that f.write does not allow me to set pickle to false. I could use `np.save` which does allow `allow_picke=False` but `np.save` doesnt allow for the constant appending everytime it is called.

I tried using np.save and writing out only when a certain number of samples had been read - but not very elegant:

```
    save_flag = False

    if (self.stateful_index < 50000 and not save_flag):
        self.test_samp = np.append(self.test_samp, samples)
    else:
        save_flag = True
        #self.f2.write(self.test_samp.astype(np.complex128).tobytes, allow_pickle=False)
        np.save(self.f2, self.test_samp, allow_pickle=False)
```

Surely there is a cleaner way I can save and append `samples` to a file with pickle set to False?

Comment: `np.save` writes a whole array, with header and databuffer, each time it's called, even when the file is opened in append mode. While it can be used that way, it isn't its intended use.  `allow_pickle` has more effect on `load` than on save.